# ASP.NET MVC: Access to the element of view in own view page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is part of my view:

```
<p>@Html.Label("", "TargetParam")
@Html.TextBox("TargetParamtext")</p>
<p>@Html.ActionLink("CheckParam", "ShowId", "Check", new { id = "Target" }, null)</p>
```

I need the value of TargetParamtext TextBox to pass in ActionLink (assign id) how can I do this without writing any script?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Html.BeginForm()` and manage a full POST to your action. Without using JS I see no other ways. Btw in your action you can access the value via `FormsData[]` or by adding it as a parameter of your action.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to have a dynamic link, depending on the value of the text box.

This is only possible at runtime, so you would have to resort to a scripting solution.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches can be used.

1. Use Javascript/jquery to post the data may be with @Ajax.
2. Action method with POST which accepts FormCollection as the only parameter. then access the  value of html control with the formcollection["fieldId"].

I would personally prefer the first approach.

Thanks,
Praveen